# cache empty after adding PWA to home screen on Safari iOS

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, caching, service-worker

Im building a `PWA` with `VueJS` in combination with `Ionic`. I've also installed the `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa`.

What I'm trying to achieve is storing an url param in cache with the `cache API` when a user visits the website where the `PWA` is deployed and after the `PWA` is installed to fetch that param again.

I've used the code in [this](https://link.medium.com/WYrBExHh1yb) tutorial tryning to make things work. I made a combination with the `service-worker`. The `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` generates a `registerServiceWorker.js`. Within this file I'm fetching the param from the url on the ready state. This looks as follow:

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker'
import { store } from './store/index.js'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    registrationOptions: { scope: '.' },
    async ready () {
      // get the code
      const queryString = window.location.search
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString)
      const ref = urlParams.get('ref')
      console.log(ref)
      // cache the code
      try {
        if (ref !== null && ref !== '' && ref !== undefined && ref !== 'undefined') {
          const cache = await caches.open("ref")
          const responseBody = JSON.stringify({ref: ref})
          const response = new Response(responseBody)
          await cache.put("/ref-code", response)
        }
      } catch {
        console.log('referral code not saved')
      } finally {
        store.commit("moduleMain/setInstallReady", true)
      }
    },
    registered () {
      console.log('registered')
    },
    cached () {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound () {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated () {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

After this is done, people can install the `PWA`. When the `PWA` is opened, they are being redirected to a home view. With `Ionic` I use the `ionViewWillEnter` hook to fetch the stored code from the cache. This code looks like this:

```
try {
    const cache = await caches.open("ref");
    const response = await cache.match("/ref-code")
    if (response) {
        const responseBody = await response.json()
        this.$store.commit('moduleHome/setCode', responseBody["ref"])
        this.$store.commit('moduleSettings/setCode', responseBody["ref"])

    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log("getToken error:", { error });
}
```

But after the `PWA` is installed it doesn't have this cache. When I test in in the `chrome` browser it does work.

Any thoughts on this?